# Removing proxying on a Reactive Object in vue 3 composition API

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I'm stuck on a reactivity problem. I am using Stein to create a back end in google sheets. Stein is very particular and wants request in [{}] format. I have done the following:

#### Template:

```html
<div class="field">
  <label class="label">Model #</label>
  <div class="control">
    <input
      class="input"
      placeholder="Model #"
      v-model="form.ModelNum"
    />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <label class="label">Bar Code</label>
  <div class="control">
    <input
      class="input"
      placeholder="Bar Code"
      v-model="form.Barcode"
    />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <label class="label">Serial #</label>
  <div class="control">
    <input
      class="input"
      placeholder="Serial #"
      v-model="form.SerialNum"
    />
  </div>
</div>
//etc
```

#### JS

```js
<script setup>
import { reactive, defineEmits, toRefs } from "vue";
import addRow from "../helperFunctions/addRow.js";

// Variables
let form = reactive({
  Equipment: "",
  Make: "",
  ModelNum: "",
  Barcode: "",
  SerialNum: "",
  Location: "",
  Condition: "",
});

const formArray = [];

const submitForm = function () {
  const formAsPlainObject = toRefs(form);
  formArray.push(formAsPlainObject);
  console.log(formArray);
  console.log(testArray);

  addRow(testArray);
};
```

The problem is the **formArray[]** object is still  proxied and this causes Stein to fail. Anybody have a way to strip proxy totally out. See dev tools below.

[image: Dev tools]

The top console.log is w/reactivity, the second is a hard coded testArray array object which succeds in adding a row in Sheets. I need it in this second structure. I thought reading docs that *torefs()* would strip out reactivity but apparently not. Any suggestions on how to send non-proxied version of my **formArray** most appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok This is what worked:

```
const formAsPlainObject = toRaw(form);
```

The toRaw() function removes the proxy on an object.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution.

Comment: toRaw() seems not to be always available in vue 3 components. Don't know why, though.